# Domain and range of Composite function.

Tags: functions

$f : A \to B$ and $g : B \to C$. 
So I know that $(g \circ f)(x):A\to C$.
What are the domain, codomain and range of $(f \circ g)(x)$?

Comment: Do you have a guess for what they may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$, so first you need $g(x)$ to be defined, and then you need $g(x)$ to be in the domain of $f$.  So the domain is $\{x \in B: g(x) \in A\} = g^{-1}(A)$.  You could take the codomain to be $B$ since that's the codomain of $f$.  The range is $f(g(g^{-1}(A)))$.

Answer (score 0):

Domain of $(f \circ g)(x)  $ is A and co domain is C.